# split date month and year in different fields

Tags: node.js, date

I have a date stored in my database in this format:

> 2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z

I have searched for it a lot but it shows how to get this date format but what I am looking for is want to separate this like:

```
a=yyyy,b=dd and c=mm
```

And the rest is not required because I want to show date, month and year all this three in different fields.

I want to store the date in one variable, month in another variable and year in another one.
I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/ccywo7a9/ and actually works but i want this using split in node.js

Comment: *"according to me they don't match my requirement"* - please **[edit]** the question and be more specific, linking to the other answers and explaining why they don't work for you.

Comment: edited the question,in my date format i have characters and time  as well and the answers which i saw was only for the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: Actually, it'd be better to include links to the other answers and explain in details why they don't work for you. And also include some of your code (what you've tried), and so on. Questions like "I want to do X" without showing any attempt are considered off-topic. Please take some time to read the [help/on-topic], the [ask] page and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried this and this https://jsfiddle.net/ccywo7a9/ actually works but i want this using split.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add code there, it's much better and more readable than in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```js
var Date='2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z';

var b=Date.slice(0,10);
var c=b.split('-');
var e=c[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(e.next().value);
console.log(e.next().value); 
console.log(e.next().value);
```

and gives the value in three different variables.

Output:

```html
2013
01
08
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Date is not a constructor` on chrome

Comment: save the code as date.js  as javascript file in any editor and run the cmd.In cmd access the folder in which you stored this date.js file and then write node date.js and press enter.now you will be able to see the output.Here date is passed as a string             var Date='2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z';

Answer (score 1):

Try this method.. it's convert Mongo DB date and Time format...

```
  String dateParts[] = "2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z".split("T");
        String split_date  = dateParts[0];
        String sp_time  = dateParts[1];

        System.out.println("sp_date----"+split_date);

        String dateParts2[] = sp_time.split("Z");
        String split_time = dateParts2[0];
        System.out.println("sp_time----"+split_time);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss.SSS");

        SimpleDateFormat cnv = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd hh:mm a");
        Date modified_date = null;
        try {
            modified_date = format.parse(split_date+split_time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("DATE----------------------"+cnv.format(modified_date));
```

Result :Jun 06 10:58 AM